# Why does EF.core sometimes includes invalid columns?

Tags: t-sql, ef-core-2.0

How does `EF.Core` choose it's columns?

I have these two simple classes: `Payment` and `Site`

I use this for my select list:

```
 var payments = db.Payments
       .Include(e => e.Site)
       .AsNoTracking();
```

EF.Core generates this invalid sql:

```
SELECT [e].[pay_id], [e].[amount], [e].[cheque_no], [e].[client_id], [e].[dt], [e].[last_modified], [e].[last_modified_by], [e].[pay_dt], [e].[pay_mode], [e].[site_id], [e.Site].[site_id], [e.Site].[address], [e.Site].[client_id], [e.Site].[last_modified], [e.Site].[last_modified_by], [e.Site].[name], [e.Site].[state]
FROM [Payments] AS [e]
INNER JOIN [Sites] AS [e.Site] ON [e].[site_id] = [e.Site].[site_id]
ORDER BY [e.Site].[name]
```

There is no `client_id` in the `Payments` table or `Payment` class below

```
  public class Payment
  {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int32 pay_id { get; set; }

    public DateTime? dt { get; set; }
    public Int32 site_id { get; set; }
    public Decimal? amount { get; set; }
    public DateTime? pay_dt { get; set; }
    public String pay_mode { get; set; }
    public String cheque_no { get; set; }

    public virtual Site Site { get; set; }

    public DateTime? last_modified { get; set; }
    public int? last_modified_by { get; set; }
  }

  public class Site
  {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Int32 site_id { get; set; }

    public String name { get; set; }
    public Int32 client_id { get; set; }
    public String address { get; set; }
    public String state { get; set; }

    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

    public List<Deployment> Deployments { get; set; }
    public List<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
    public List<Timesheet> Timesheets { get; set; }

    public DateTime? last_modified { get; set; }
    public int? last_modified_by { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: *There is no `client_id` in the `Payments` table or `Payment` class below* The question is then, does `Client` class contain collection (list, enumerable) of `Payment`?

Comment: I see now `public List<Payment> Payments { get; set; }` is in client class. Thanks